# Siri Shorcuts launches Application always

Tags: ios, ios12, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have added Siri Shortcuts in my phone and whenever I call the shortcut in the Siri, it opens the iOS Application.

It doesn't execute the intent which i have wrote.

Following is my IntentHandler.swift

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension {

    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.

        return self
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found any resolution @Vittal Pai?

Comment: @NiravJain I don't remember it now, the below answer might help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved it by returning the instance of intent handler.

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension {

    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.

        return ViewPointsIntentHandler()
    }

}
```

and added the following methods in the `AppDelegate` file where `ViewPointsIntent` is the intent of the Siri Shortcut.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let intent = userActivity.interaction?.intent as? ViewPointsIntent {
            handle(intent)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

private func handle(_ intent: ViewPointsIntent) {
        let handler = ViewPointsIntentHandler()
        handler.handle(intent: intent) { (response) in
            print("success")
        }
    }
```